# How do I work around a container div needed to expand in IE without setting a width to it?

Tags: internet-explorer, html

I need the container to expand based upon the information input in it, but in IE it automatically expands to 100% because there is no width set on the container, but setting a width on the container would limit the information allowed inside and shift the containing information. The container is absolutely positioned and the divs inside are floating.

Comment: You may want to show what code you have so far so we can see what you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Put this inside of your container and see if that helps.